# Meteor only working when deployed in debug mode

Tags: meteor, meteorite

Hi I have a meteor application that's working fine when running locally.
But when i deploy it to a meteor website or bundle to deploy it on another server it doesn't work.

Strangely if I deploy in debug mode, `meteor deploy --debug example.meteor.com` it works.

I'm using meteor and meteorite, and some jquery plugins that i include as files

Any clue of what might be the problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your javascript console for errors.

You likely have a syntax error somewhere or you're trying to access a variable that is undefined. When the files are concatenated and minified the syntax error stops the rest of the script running.

In debug mode the files are separated so it won't stop the other files code from running. This is probably why it works in debug mode but not in production mode.

Another quick test is to see if `meteor --production` doesn't work.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I just ignored an error as it worked on my local machine and really couldn't find the problem .. Simple solution :)

Answer (score 0):

> "Solved by adding jquery as a meteor AND npm package..."

I was also getting the error message `jQuery not found`. Based on @Akshat's answer and [this Github post](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/10835), I ran the following and got it working:

```
meteor add jquery
meteor npm i jquery --save
```